# python dateutil relativedelta value out of range error

Tags: python, django

i am trying to get two dates, yesterday's and tomorrow's based on a given date which i then pass on to Django's Queryset filter function:

```
nxtday = relativedelta(day=+1) + date
yesterday = relativedelta(day=-1) + date
events = events.filter(start_datetime__gte=yesterday, end_datetime__lte=nxtday)
```

The point here is to get the events for the day as you've already probably deduced. Problem is i keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Switching to timedelta objects  raises issues later with dateutil's rrule:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

I am fond of dateutil module so i am just curious why it didn't work. Example date passed: 2014-02-26. Any ideas?

Comment: What type of object is `date`?  Also is it naive or aware?

Comment: date is a python datetime.date and it is naive, that's the problem that arises later on with rrule when i switch to using timedelta objects, it seems rrule expects timezone aware instances

Comment: `relativedelta` does not support having the date on the right hand side of the `+`, use `date + relativedelta(day=+1)`.  You will probably now get the second error in both cases, as that is your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Passing -1 for the day parameter is requesting the -1 day of the month, which is why it complains about an out of range value.

For relative delta the *day* parameter is for absolute dates, and the *days* parameter is for relative dates.  [docs](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-6a1472b7c74e5b8bab7784f11214250d34e09aa5)

```
nxtday = relativedelta(days=1) + date
yesterday = relativedelta(days=-1) + date
```